# jQuery resizable() não arrasta o panel-footer

Tags: jquery, resize

Quando eu aplico o resizable no panel e arrasto para baixo, o footer não vem com o panel.

Alguma forma para resolver este problema?

O código é o seguinte:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default" id="resizable">
  <div class="panel-body">A Basic Panel</div>
  <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
</div>

<script>
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
  handles: "s"
});
</script>
```

Exemplo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/unnqmnd8/1/)

Comment: Eu tive o mesmo problema e não achei uma solução simples para resolver isto, inclusive acrescentei na sua pergunta um exemplo disto, verifique e veja se é este mesmo o problema :)

Comment: exactamente, é esse o problema obrigado!

Comment: @Espiga, veja se este exemplo lhe serve, caso sirva preparo a resposta...
http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/unnqmnd8/6/

Comment: sim serve perfeitamente obrigado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que fiz foi adicionar a sua class `panel` um `min-height`, para que não houvesse uma diminuição que fizesse com que os objeto colidissem, e um `overflow:  hidden` para que o que tivesse dentro nos painéis não transbordassem.

```
.panel{
  min-height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Já no `footer` o que fez a diferença foi o `position: absolute` e o `bottom: 0`, dessa maneira ele ficará fixo, independente do tamanho do `.panel`.

```
.panel-footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Obs.:** Usei o mesmo `handles: "s"` da pergunta, pois assim, o usuário só poderá redimensionar apenas verticalmente e na parte inferior. Caso não queira isso, queira um redimensionamento total, basta retirar o `handles` e adicionar um `min-height/width` e um `max-height/width` ao `.panel` de acordo com o que você deseja, para que, como o @Highlander disse, o usuário não fique brincando com o layout.

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/unnqmnd8/7/)

Comment: Quando tive este problema não tinha achado uma solução boa que só levasse css, top msm, não seria interessante incluir um min-height/width para o usuario não ficar zoando o layout ?

Comment: @Highlander, acrescentei um `handles: "s"`, dentro do `.resizable()` para que só seja possível redimensionar na parte inferior, de acordo com o código da pergunta. Acho que vou acrescentar isso a resposta rsrs.

Comment: Não que seja um problema por que é uma ação do usuario, mas o handles: "s" permite redimensionar para cima cobrindo o texto.

Comment: Assim fica livre para o autor, ele customiza o `min-height` de acordo com o que ele quer, pensei em criar um script para o `min` ser do tamanho do conteúdo, mas não sei se isso seria tão bom...

Comment: perfeito obrigado!

Comment: De nada @Espiga...